Connecting two network namespaces over a bridge
I'm trying to make one network namespace to be able to ping another namespace via a bridge.
Here are the commands I'm executing:
# create two namespaces
ip netns add ns0
ip netns add ns1

# create a bridge
ip link add brg0 type bridge
ip link set dev brg0 up

# create two virtual cables
ip link add eth0_ns0 type veth peer name eth0_brg0
ip link add eth0_ns1 type veth peer name eth1_brg0

# associating each interface to the corresponding device
ip link set eth0_ns0 netns ns0
ip link set eth0_ns1 netns ns1

ip link set eth0_brg0 master brg0
ip link set eth1_brg0 master brg0

# adding ip addresses
ip netns exec ns0 ip addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev eth0_ns0
ip netns exec ns1 ip addr add 10.10.10.11/24 dev eth0_ns1

# setting interfaces up
ip netns exec ns0 ip link set eth0_ns0 up
ip netns exec ns0 ip link set lo up
ip netns exec ns1 ip link set eth0_ns1 up
ip netns exec ns1 ip link set lo up

# setting bridge interfaces up
ip link set eth0_brg0 up
ip link set eth1_brg0 up

Finally, when I issue ip netns exec ns0 ping 10.10.10.11, ping fails. Why? What do I miss?
NOTE: Please don't suggest to make the connectivity without a bridge. This is just an example. The actual need is 50 namespaces connected together via a bridge.
And for the record, it's working fine using only two namespaces without a bridge.
UPDATE: output of iptables-save as requested:
root@zam:~# iptables-save
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Thu May 16 17:15:21 2024
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 16 17:15:21 2024
# Generated by xtables-save v1.8.2 on Thu May 16 17:15:21 2024
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 16 17:15:21 2024
root@zam:~# sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Update: Output of ip route:
root@zam:~# ip route
default via 192.168.100.1 dev eth0 onlink
192.168.100.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.100.2
172.1.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.1.0.1 linkdown

Update: Output of ip -n ns0 addr and ip -n ns1 addr
root@zam:~# ip -n ns0 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
161: eth0_ns0@if160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 5e:43:df:59:9c:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.10.10.10/24 scope global eth0_ns0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5c43:dfff:fe59:9c32/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@zam:~# ip -n ns1 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
163: eth0_ns1@if162: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:28:4b:09:e5:e0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.10.10.11/24 scope global eth0_ns1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1c28:4bff:fe09:e5e0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Update: Output of ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:28:62:da brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.2/23 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::2e0:4cff:fe28:62da/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:22:32:35:0d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
159: brg0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:cf:8d:ab:c1:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::c048:c0ff:fe06:481a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
160: eth0_brg0@if161: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brg0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:cf:8d:ab:c1:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns ns0
    inet6 fe80::accf:8dff:feab:c17b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
162: eth1_brg0@if163: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master brg0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:37:14:66:63:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns ns1
    inet6 fe80::d437:14ff:fe66:638e/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


Can you also add the output of ip route?

Linux is genial and so are you, Ahmed!

@larsks
I've updated with the output of 'ip route'. Thanks!

You need to enable ip forwarding in your kernel:
syctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

With forwarding enabled, your setup works as written:
[root@localhost ~]# sh setup-network.sh
[root@localhost ~]# ip netns exec ns0 ping -c1 10.10.10.11
PING 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.11: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms

--- 10.10.10.11 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.132/0.132/0.132/0.000 ms
[root@localhost ~]# ip netns exec ns1 ping -c1 10.10.10.10
PING 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.10.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms

--- 10.10.10.10 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.056/0.056/0.056/0.000 ms


After the above changes, your environment still isn't working as expected.

My first thought was that there could be firewall rules in place that were blocking the traffic, but your FORWARD chain has a default policy of ACCEPT and there are not any matching rules that would otherwise prevent traffic between the namespaces.

My second through was that there could be a conflicts between the address range you're using for your namespaces and another local network, but the output of ip route shows that is not the case.


On my Debian 10 system, running your firewall rules, everything works as expected.
I'm out of obvious things to check. For really weird network problems I often reach for pwru, which utilizes eBPF to instrument the kernel to trace packets through a variety of kernel network functions...but it looks like the kernel in Debian 10 is too old to support this.
Just to make sure we're not missing something obvious, can you add to your question the output of:
ip addr
ip -n ns0 addr
ip -n ns1 addr

I don't think we're going to spot anything there, but it's worth a try.

Thanks for the answer. Thumbs up. I had already actually enabled ip forwarding, because I found it on another site while trying to solve the issue. However, it didn't help. And obviously, you just copied my steps and tried it on your machine and apparently it's working. So, I'm not sure what's wrong with my machine. What might be disabled. I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster). Any more suggestions? Thanks again.

Do you have any firewall rules in place that could be blocking traffic? Maybe update your question with the output of iptables-save. And I guess add the output of sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward as well, just to confirm that it's set right now.

I've updated with the requested info. Please check. Thanks!

I've updated the output for 'ip addr'. While pasting the output, I've noticed that the interfaces numbering just jump from 3 to 159. Does that mean that there might be hidden undeleted interfaces? Maybe those undeleted interfaces are the ones causing problems? Again, thanks a lot for the keen follow-up.

ip_forward sysctl is for L3 forwarding. L2 bridges perform L2 forwarding. It's true that iptables / nftables forward filtering could be applied to L2 forwarding though (br_netfilter).
